# how to get variable value within function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I return the variable value within the function?

```
var myString = "px";
var myMethod = function(){
    if(myString == 'percent') {
        return '%';
    } else {
        return myString; // should return 'px'
    }
$('div').css('width','200'+myMethod()); //not working
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ym4n/)

As I'm having problem with this:

```
var sCalc = this.className.split('-')[4];
    var fnCalc = function(){
        if(sCalc == 'plus'){
            return '+';
        } else if(sCalc == 'minus'){
            return '-';
        } else if(sCalc == 'multiply'){
            return '*';
        } else if(sCalc == 'divide'){
            retutn '/';
        } else{
            return '+';
        } /*bugging me this too much*/
    };
```

I'm not seeing any error in my console?

Comment: You can clearly point the error in console itself..

Comment: In terms of the second set of code you pasted, you have a typo: `retutn '/';` should be `return '/';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a curly brace to end your function.

```
var myString = "px";
var myMethod = function() {
    if (myString == 'percent') {
        return '%';
    } else {
        return myString; // should return 'px'
    }
};
$('div').css('width','200'+myMethod()); //not working
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ym4n/4/)

Comment: alternatively you could use `var myString = "px";
var myMethod = (myString == 'percent') ? myMethod = '%' : myMethod = myString;
$('div').css('width','200'+myMethod);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>  
  var myString = "px";
    var myMethod = function(){
        if(myString=='percent'){
            return '%';
        } else {
            alert(myString); // should return 'px'
        }
    }
    $('div').css('width','200'+myMethod());
</script>
<div style="background: red; position: absolute;">test</div>
```